# CentOS - Mongo class not found in PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, classnotfound

I need the MongoDB PHP driver on my CentOS 5.4 machine. My PHP version is 5.1.6. I downloaded the RPM and installed it. That created several files in /usr/bin directory. I copied

```
/usr/bin/mongo
```

to

```
/usr/lib/php/modules
```

which was what extension_dir showed on doing phpinfo();.

I also added

```
extension=mongo.so
```

in /etc/php.ini.
However on executing my PHP script, i still get

```
Mongo class not found.
```

What's going wrong here ?

Also, my phpinfo() shows PHP version 5.1.6 whereas running PHP from command line shows 5.3.3. Could anything be wrong with that ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you edit the right `php.ini`? Did you restart your server? Try `phpinfo()`

Comment: When you say you installed the RPM which one to you mean? PHP? Mongo? or the Mongo PHP extension?

Comment: Run `php -m | grep mongo` from the command line. If you get nothing check you edited the correct ini file and that it is being loaded with `php --ini`

Comment: Yup !! Edited the php.ini that showed up in phpingo(). Restarted the server too !!

Comment: @Cygnus: Are you by any chance using a namespace?

Comment: I must also mention that /usr/bin/mongo is a binary executable file but its not having a .so  extension. Im copying it as is to /usr/lib/php/modules.

Comment: Have you tried `whereis php.ini`? Are you using DirectAdmin? If so, you've likely now got two copies of PHP installed - this happened to me. Delete the new installation and find the `php.ini` / PHP directory from your DirectAdmin installation.

Comment: @dunc : When i do find / -name php.ini, i get 3 results -

/etc/php.ini
/opt/php-5.3.3/php.ini
/opt/lampp/etc/php.ini

Comment: Sounds like you have multiple installations on the go Cygnus, though they're not the DirectAdmin install paths. I would try moving your files to `/opt/php-5.3.3` and editing that path's `php.ini`.

Comment: @Cygnus a .so is a Linux [shared libary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_library#Shared_libraries) file (similar to a DLL on Windows).  In this case mongo.so is intended for use by the Apache server, and is not the same as the command-line [`mongo` executable](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/mongo+-+The+Interactive+Shell) which gets installed in your bin directory.

Comment: @dunc : I should choose that coz thats the new version right ?

Comment: Just a guess to be honest, but I think it's worth a try, yeah. You'll likely have to delete your new installation though. You'll also, somehow, have to tell Apache which PHP installation to use? Unfortunately that's a bit beyond my skill-set but I do believe it to be the problem you're having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're saying your webserver and command line PHP report different versions. These are going to be installed in different locations, and their extensions are API incompatible with each other.

When you installed the php_mongo extension, it may have used the command line php to determine the directory to install the extension to.

Make sure you have the correct php_mongo for the php version of your webserver, and it is in the correct extensions directory. (get the directory from the php.ini returned by `phpinfo()`)

I hope you realise PHP 5.1 is also many years out of date. Unless you have a specific reason to use a version that old, you should also look at upgrading to a more recent version.

**Edit:**

Just read your comment *"I must also mention that /usr/bin/mongo is a binary executable file but its not having a .so extension. Im copying it as is to /usr/lib/php/modules"*

No no no! :)

This is the mongo command line client. This is not the PHP extension!

You can run a `find /* -name "mongo.so"` to see where the installer put the file, this will probably also give you an indication of which version of PHP it was installed for.

Comment: Damn !! You're right !! i was confusing between the two. Never thought of that beczuse i thought i was using the right thing !! Thanks a lot.. Will make the corrections now.

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though you are confusing the RPM-packages for the MongoDB server with the requirements to install the [MongoDB PHP driver](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php#mongo.installation.nix).  The PHP driver provides access to the server from your PHP applications, and does not install any command line tools.

Answer (score 0):

restart httpd !

```
yum service httpd restart
```